# Difference between modifying and non-modifying putback()

Tags: c++

The question comes from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback, the example code.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream s2("Hello, world"); // input-only stream
    s2.get();
    if (s2.putback('Y')) // cannot modify input-only buffer
        std::cout << s2.rdbuf() << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "putback failed\n";

    s2.clear();
    if (s2.putback('H')) // non-modifying putback
        std::cout << s2.rdbuf() << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "putback failed\n";
}
```

Why `s2.putback('Y')` fails but `s2.putback('H')` succeed? Isn't the latter also an operation to modify the input-only stream buffer?

---

Also, I find something confusing while doing some experiments.
I add 1 line code compared to the sample above and the second results fails.. Why is it?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream s2("Hello, world"); // input-only stream
    s2.get();
    if (s2.putback('Y')) // cannot modify input-only buffer
        std::cout << s2.rdbuf() << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "putback failed\n";

    std::cout << s2.rdbuf() << '\n';   //1 line code added

    s2.clear();
    if (s2.putback('H')) // non-modifying putback
        std::cout << s2.rdbuf() << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "putback failed\n";

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read further the behavior of [`sputbackc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/sputbackc).

> If a putback position is available in the get area (`gptr() > eback()`), and the character c is equal to the character one position to the left of `gptr()` (as determined by `Traits::eq(c, gptr()[-1])`, then simply decrements the next pointer (`gptr()`).

So in the case of `s2.putback('H')`, only the next pointer is decremented. The buffer is not changed.

---

Answer to your edit: [`basic_ostream& operator<<( std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>* sb);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) extracts the characters maintained by `sb`, so after `std::cout << s2.rdbuf() << '\n';` the next pointer points to the end of the buffer, which causes `s2.putback('H')` to fail.

Answer (score 4):

> Why `s2.putback('Y')` fails but `s2.putback('H')` succeed? Isn't the latter also an operation to modify the input-only stream buffer?

The invocation `s2.putback('H')` *potentially* modifies the buffer, but in this case, it does not, because the data already start with an `'H'`.

You can exemplify the behavior like this:

```
s2.clear();

assert(s2.putback('H')); // Ok, replacing 'H' with 'H' doesn't change anything
assert(!s2.putback('Z')); // Can't modify.
```

Comment: I don't know much about a underlying buffer object. But here's how I understand, after `c2.get()`, calling `std::cout << s2.rdbuf()`, I get the rest of the buffer which remains `"ello, world"`. Then by `s2.putback('H')`, the buffer becomes `"Hello, world"` again, why this doesn't count as a modification?

Comment: @Rick Because the contents of the stream have not changed, only the recorded position of the "get" pointer. If this was a disk file - nothing on the disk would need to change.

Comment: @Galik I think I lack knowledge of `basic_streambuf` and it makes me really hard to understand the whole thing.

Comment: @Rick It is about whether or not you can take out of the stream something that was not originally there. By using an `istream` you elect a stream that can not be written to, only read from. By rejecting a `putback` of a character than was not already in the stream it maintains that "input only" guarantee.